# Gfortran: Large Arrays do not work on M1 Mac

Tags: fortran, homebrew, apple-m1, gfortran

My Fortran code is not working on my M1 Mac (Ventura 13.5) anymore. Here is a simple example.

```
program mwe
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: nx=500
    integer, parameter :: ny=500
    integer, parameter :: nz=500
    integer, parameter :: ncol=4

    integer :: image(nx, ny, nz, ncol-1)
    double precision :: alpha(nx, ny, nz)

    image = 0
    alpha = 0.0

end program mwe
```

Commenting out either `array` or `image` (declaration & assignment) causes the code to work fine. But with both uncommented, I get this when I run it:

```
dyld[10519]: dyld cache '(null)' not loaded: syscall to map cache into shared region failed
dyld[10519]: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
  Referenced from: <43A71502-FD1F-3929-A1F3-3102B17ACF2D> /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/fortran_mwe/a.out
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib' (no such file, no dyld cache), '/usr/local/lib/libSystem.B.dylib' (no such file)
Abort trap: 6
```

There are some [discussions](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/64896) online, allocatable arrays seem to work, but are not an option in my case. Any help is appreciated!

---

**Edit:** Info requested in comments:

Output from `otool -l your_binary | fgrep -B1 -A10 LC_SEGMENT_64`:

```
Load command 0
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 72
  segname __PAGEZERO
   vmaddr 0x0000000000000000
   vmsize 0x0000000100000000
  fileoff 0
 filesize 0
  maxprot 0x00000000
 initprot 0x00000000
   nsects 0
    flags 0x0
Load command 1
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 392
  segname __TEXT
   vmaddr 0x0000000100000000
   vmsize 0x0000000000004000
  fileoff 0
 filesize 16384
  maxprot 0x00000005
 initprot 0x00000005
   nsects 4
    flags 0x0
--
Load command 2
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 152
  segname __DATA_CONST
   vmaddr 0x0000000100004000
   vmsize 0x0000000000004000
  fileoff 16384
 filesize 16384
  maxprot 0x00000003
 initprot 0x00000003
   nsects 1
    flags 0x10
--
Load command 3
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 152
  segname __DATA
   vmaddr 0x0000000100008000
   vmsize 0x0000000095030000
  fileoff 0
 filesize 0
  maxprot 0x00000003
 initprot 0x00000003
   nsects 1
    flags 0x0
--
Load command 4
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 72
  segname __LINKEDIT
   vmaddr 0x0000000195038000
   vmsize 0x0000000000004000
  fileoff 32768
 filesize 898
  maxprot 0x00000001
 initprot 0x00000001
   nsects 0
    flags 0x0
```

Output from `otool -l your_binary | fgrep -B1 -A3 LC_MAIN`:

```
Load command 13
       cmd LC_MAIN
   cmdsize 24
  entryoff 16140
 stacksize 0
```

Comment: Well, that alpha() array needs 1GB memory ... on the stack. If you use allocatable arrays then it will go on the heap, which modern computers should find straightforward to accommodate. Why are allocatable arrays "not an option"?

Comment: this will be compiled with f2py as part of a python module and f2py has limited support for allocatable arrays as far as I know.

Comment: What happens if you compile with option ```-fno-stack-arrays``` ?

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: Actually, array image() is worse: it will require 2GB. If I make those arrays allocatable and then allocate them to size then there is no problem. I don't use f2py, but I would explore what exactly it can do with allocatable arrays. Maybe have a look at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/python-usage.html#allocatable-arrays

Comment: It is after all about the most basic possible use of allocateable arrays ...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Will try and report back. Still it works on a linux machine and  my Mac has plenty of memory, so it should work.

Comment: You are missing the point - this has little to do with how much memory your machine has. It has to do with how the operating system organises the memory on the machine in question. You are trying to store large arrays on the stack given to you by the OS. This is designed for small arrays, a few 10s of kBytes at most. So trying to store large arrays there is a Bad Idea full stop. On Unix like systems they should go on the heap - use allocatabkes for this. The reason it works on the "mainframe" is that whoever set it up has given you a very large stack. You can't be sure of this in general.

Comment: I'm curious how this is encoded. Does the Fortran compiler tell the linker to embed info in the output binary to make the stack absolutely massive? Because the error above indicates that the kernel reserved so much memory for your binary (about 2GB, starting at 0x100000000 plus ASLR slide) that it overlaps with the dyld shared cache region (at 0x180000000). Can you post the output of `otool -l your_binary | fgrep -B1 -A10 LC_SEGMENT_64` and `otool -l your_binary | fgrep -B1 -A3 LC_MAIN`?

Comment: The arrays are actually static, not on the stack. They would end up on the stack e.g. when using OpenMP or possibly if they were local to a procedure. But the main points remain, it is about memory organization by the OS.

Comment: Ok, using allocatable arrays works. For f2py, one need to use module variables then, so the downside would be that one needs to use those module variables after running the subroutine (or write a python wrapper that calls the routine and returns the arrays) and the solution is not thread-save, any parallelization needs to happen inside the fortran routine as far as I understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binary has a `__DATA` segment of 2.5GB virtual memory size. With a binary at the default load address of `0x100000000`, that's gonna extend into the region reserved for the dyld_shared_cache that contains all the system libraries at `0x180000000`. Both regions are subject to ASLR so the runtime addresses will diverge a bit, but 2.5GB is comfortably too much.

The quick and dirty fix is to lower the default load address:

```
-Wl,-pagezero_size,0x10000
```

This will give you about 3.9GB more space that your binary can occupy.

A fix that's less hacky would be to move these massive arrays into a shared library, which can be loaded anywhere by dyld and doesn't have to fit before the 0x180000000 region.

Note, however, that you're really pushing the limit here. If the virtual memory size of your binary ever grows past 4GB, various thing start breaking and dyld will almost certainly fail to load your binary. So of course the proper fix here would be to allocate such large amounts of memory dynamically at runtime.